# What's the meaning of phrase "A is one to forget for B on the whole"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> The summer just gone was one to forget for Korea's tourism industry on
>   the whole.

What's the meaning of phrase "A is one to forget for B on the whole"?

I guess it means something like that Korea's tourism industry was sluggish during the summer which is just gone, but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [original article is here.](http://www.arirang.com/News/News_View.asp?nseq=184304) It is about a marked decline in tourism industry in Korea.

By that sentence, the writer means that this summer was very bad in terms of having tourists. The tourism department *wants to forget* this (and probably hope that it should never happen again). '[on the whole' is an idiom](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-whole) meaning 'generally i.e. in general'.

Comment: Note that unless the Tourism Organization (aka KTO in South Korea) announced such sentiment in the news, the news wouldn't really say "The tourism department wants to forget this".