# What is the correct meaning of "I didn't want to be the one to forget"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

The first line of the Daft Punk's song "Instant crush" is "I didn't want to be the one to forget". This has two different meanings to me:

1. I didn't want to be the person, who forgets the past.
2. I didn't want to be the person, whom everybody else forgets about.

Which one is correct, if any?

**Update 1:** In Russian I see both translations. So, I'm confused.

**Update 2:** I've found a video [The One to Forget](https://youtu.be/c5Y9RfYVMW0) (36 seconds)
Am I right that it's a pun? The nickname of the rightmost guy, as I understand it, is **The124get**, so he's always the one to forget as explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/71025/123030) (when others want to forget about something bad or inappropriate), and this is because the others are talking about him, not he about himself. Right?

Comment: Song lyrics are notoriously ambiguous, even if they have any meaning at all. Could mean either. Or both. Or neither.

Answer (score 0):

> Song lyrics are notoriously ambiguous, even if they have any meaning at all.

However the English verb "to forget" as an active verb means that the subject ("I") stops remembering something.  So the meaning must be sense 1 in your question.

Sense 2 would be expressed as "I didn't want to be the one to be forgotten."

What the song writers (who are not English) intended to mean is beyond our ken.

Comment: Thanks, @james-k!  

Thanks, @michael-harvey!  

I've found the short video [The One to Forget] (https://youtu.be/c5Y9RfYVMW0) (36 seconds)  
Am I right that it's a pun? The nickname of the rightmost guy, as I understand it, is ** The124get **, so he's always the one to forget as explained [here] (https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/71025/123030), and that's because the others are talking about him, not he about himself.  Right?